# Printing elements of an array and checking another

Tags: java, arrays

Some exam revision here from a past paper.

My declared array is :

```
String letterArray = {g,p,l,w,r}
```

Would you personally use String or char ?

Second up, i need to printout the 3rd element of this array, would this simply be

```
System.out.print(letterArray[2]) // arrays start at zero
```

third i need to check the 4th element contains a 'y', making sure the user is informed if it contains a y or not.

would this be:

```
if(letterArray[3] == y)
{
    System.out.println("It contains y");
} 
else 
{
    System.out.println("It does not contain a y");
}
```

sorry if ive missed characters as im on mobile with no compiler handy.

Comment: The number four question should be "why doesn't it compile?" ;-)   (hint: you are missing single quotes around your character constants)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Always format your code correctly with proper indentation, and  `String` is not `char[]` in java. `String` itself is a data type and `char[]` is another type and `char` literal are specified with single quote around them and String literal is specified with double quote around them: `'a'` is `char` but `"a"` is of type  `String`

Comment: You're gonna need to use double quotes (`"`) around strings. Also, for string comparison you should use `myString.equals("blah")` not `mystring == "blah"`. If you use `char` instead you will have to use single quotes (`'`) but you'll be able to use `==` for comparison.

Comment: If your array indeed consists of letters (single characters), then 3rd task is formulated in deliberately convoluted way.

Comment: Sorry about the single quotes etc, im on mobile so no compiler to hand. also using the ancient method of pen and paper for this revision, thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

- *Would you personally use String or char?* Because the array is suppose to hold just 1 letter per entry I would go with `char` for clarity and easy checking.
- *`System.out.print(letterArray[2])`* yes that prints the 3rd entry in the array
- *i need to check the 4th element contains a 'y', making sure...* Yes that code works. Remember that if you plan to use == you need to use primitive data types. Also you need to wrap your strings/chars in quotes (`'` for char `"` for strings)

Char version:

```
 char [] letterArray = {'g','p','l','w','r'};
 if(letterArray[3] == 'y') {
     System.out.print("It contains y");
 } else {
     System.out.println("It does not contain a y");
 }
```

String array:

```
 String [] letterArray = {"g","p","l","w","r"};
 if(letterArray[3].equals("y")) {
     System.out.print("It contains y");
 } else {
     System.out.println("It does not contain a y");
 }
```

Now remeber strings are really char arrays..

```
 String string = "gplwr";
 if(string.charAt(3) == 'y') {
     System.out.print("It contains y");
 } else {
     System.out.println("It does not contain a y");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run this method,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    char[] letterArray = new char[] {'g','p','l','w','r'};
    // based on your variable name, I'd use a char array.
    System.out.println(letterArray[2]); // get's the 3rd element ('l')
    if(letterArray[3] == 'y') // test if the fourth element is a 'y'
    {
      System.out.println("It contains y");
    } 
    else 
    {
      System.out.println("It does not contain a y");
    }
}
```

it outputs

```
l
It does not contain a y
```

Answer (score 0):

> My declared array is : String letterArray = {g,p,l,w,r} Would you
>   personally use String or char ?

Use char unless you plan to have anything longer than one char.

Also, you should probably put the chars in quotes:

```
letterArray = {'g','p','l','w','r'}
```

> Second up, i need to printout the 3rd element of this array, would
>   this simply be
>
> System.out.print(letterArray[2]) // arrays start at zero

This is correct

> third i need to check the 4th element contains a 'y', making sure the
>   user is informed if it contains a y or not.
>
> would this be: if(letterArray[3] == y){system.out.print("It contains
>   y")} else {System.out.println("It does not contain a y")}

Very close, but since we put the chars in quotes you would want to do this:

```
(letterArray[3] == 'y'){system.out.print("It contains y")} else {System.out.println("It does not contain a y")}
```